# check the state of a radio button android and count the answers

Tags: android, radio-button

I edited the code the way @CommonsWare told me
i get force close when I try to click r1 and the problem is it seems button[i].isChecked() doesn;t work--> fixed

I have `final RadioButton[] buttons = {r1,r3,r5,r7};`

And I want to count them (basically yes answers)

```
public void onClick(View view){


    checkStates(buttons);}
}
private void  checkStates(RadioButton[] buttons) { 
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].isChecked())

             yes++;}
     if (yes>=3){
      Intent intent=new Intent(this,AnotherClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
  }

  }
```

Basically I have yes and no radio buttons. I want to count the yes answers and if the user changes their mind and checks no to decrement yes

r1 r3 r5 etc are "yes" answers
r2 r4 r6 are "no" answers

My approach might be wrong since I'm new to this but if someone helps me I'll post the whole thing for people to see.

Please help!

Ok I checked the log cat and i receive the following error (it was obvious where but I don't know why and how can I implement this to work)

```
Android Runtime:  Uncaught handler :thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

java.lang.NullPointerException  
RadioButtons.checkStates(RadioButtons.java:49) --> here  : if (buttons[i].isChecked()) 
RadioButtons.onClick(RadioButtons.java:42)--> here:    checkStates(buttons);
```

Edit:The problem - the way @CommonsWare pointed out-was that `buttons` wasn;t initialized and I got `NullPointerException` So I changed the code before with this one:`RadioButton[]buttons =new RadioButton[3];` gave the size of the array

```
 public void onClick(View view){
checkStates(buttons);
      }
private void  checkStates(RadioButton[] buttons) { 
        buttons[0]=rb1;
        buttons[1]=rb3;
        buttons[2]=rb5;

        if (buttons[i].isChecked()){

               yes++;}
           tv.setText("Result:"+yes);

    }
```

The problem this time is that It still counts the clicks and not the "yes" answers
I have the following problems to resolve

- count the "yes" answers yes++
- If the user clicks the second time don't count
- If the user changes their mind from "yes" to "no" decrement "yes"
- If the user presses "no" Don't count anything (the important part of my       application is to count the yes answers   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check the state of a radio button in android?

Call `isChecked()`. But you knew this already.

> And I want to count them

There is no point in calling `setChecked(true)` on a `RadioButton` that returns true from `isChecked()`, since that `RadioButton` is already checked.

> I want to count the yes answers and if the user changes their mind and checks no to decrement yes

Replace your `// if r1 or r3 are checked{` with `if buttons[i].isChecked() {`

Comment: I tried the way you told me but it doesn;t work with buttons[i].isChecked() only with r1.isChecked()...I get force close everytime I click r1 and although someone advised to do it like this this approach also counts the clicks not the answer. Is there another way where I could somehow count the radiobuttons if they are already checked not to increment?

Comment: @Michiru: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

Comment: @CommonsWare It is of course related with this code (I edited the post with the error) although yesterday I got force close also and it was because of my xml file. This time it's got to be because of the array . Could you please tell me what you think at a first glance? I know NullPointerException is because of array initialization . I admit I am newbie but I'm also kinda time pressed sorry to bug you like this.

Comment: @Michiru: `buttons[i]` is `null` for some value of `i`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the subtle tip :D you actually knew what the problem was you just pointed the direction. Thanks it helped. But now I have another problem. It still counts the clicks. I edited AGAIN the post with my current code. It counts the clicks. I want to not count when the user clicks the second time(or third time etc) and to decrement when the user changes their mind from yes to no. Any other ideas or should I give up this approach? Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use a RadioGroup to group each Yes and No pair so that Both are not allowed to be selected in the same time.

Here is a great starting resource
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons

Read this page and all your questions will be answered, including how to setup OnClickListener

Hope this helps

Comment: I already put them in a radio group I forgot to add that :). Thanks for letting me know anyway